# IAP iOS UIAlertView cancel button

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I'm using StoreKit for implement purchacing in my app. My question is how can I hendle UIAlertView when IAP dialog appear. I need to process Cancel button. I need to know when I press cancel and notify my system about this. I need to process cancel button that on alert view that request my user and password data.

For example if user tap on cancel button it should invoke some callback method.

Comment: its been 10 years now and still Apple does not give us callback for this !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can handle it in [SKPaymentTransactionObserver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Something like this

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {
               if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
               {
                   //user cancelled purchase
                }
             }  
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't invoke this mehod wen I tap on cancel button

Comment: otherwise I can invoke this method if I tap on buy button

Comment: sorry I have make mistake. it's dialog that request my password